# Filter out or overload method

Tags: c#, logic

I have a dilemma that I need help with. The method `TAXCheckControlNumberForAccuracy` goes into the database and does a `Select *` statement using the passed in variables.

However, each time the program runs any one of these variables could be null. All could be null. None could be null. (i'm using OCR to get the variables..so it is not always accurate)

Can someone give me some insight on the best way to solve this problem.

```
if ((City != null) && (Zip != null) && (State != null) && (Owner != null))
            {
                if (City.Length > 4)
                {
                    ControlNumberMatch = TAXCheckControlNumberForAccuracy(Owner, Zip, State, City);
                }
            }
```

Comment: What's the problem exactly? You're already checking to see if they're null so you shouldn't hit that database select.

Comment: @Daniel said it best on one of the answers "His [my] problem is that he has four variables, but some, all or none could be null. But he always has those four variables." .... I want to run the method every time but I understand that some variables will change depending on the information that is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of what you do, you still need to check each parameter individually. Create a method that does such.

```
void string CorrectParam(string param)
{
    if (param == null)
        return "default";
    return param;
}

void TAXCheckControlNumberForAccuracy(string City, string Zip, string State, string Owner)
{
}

//call using this
TAXCheckControlNumberForAccuracy(CorrectParam(City), CorrectParam(Zip), CorrectParam(State), CorrectParam(Owner));
```

Comment: This helped me the most. I added a piece inside the method in question. `if ((_zip == "default") || (_state == "default") || (_city == "default"))
            {
                return null;
            }`

Comment: So that way if the `CorrectParam()` changes the variable to 'default' then the method will return null. Because otherwise it will fail once it tries to run the OleDb query inside `taxcheckcontrolnumberforaccuracy()`

Comment: @MaylorTaylor If you are checking each parameter in that way, can you not just check to see if they are "== null"?

Answer (score 2):

you can use a method with [optional parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx). Like

```
public void TAXCheckControlNumberForAccuracy(string Owner = "default", 
       string Zip = "default",string  State = "default",string City = "default");
```

Comment: How would that help? Optional parameters are a *compile time* feature.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth what i understood from OP question is that he wants to pass optional parameters to methods.

Comment: In that case, you misunderstood the question. His problem is that he has four variables, but some, all or none could be null. But he always has those four variables. The default value of an optional parameter is only used if you don't pass a value for that parameter. Even if the variable you pass is `null` you still pass a value, so the default values would never be used: `TAXCheckControlNumberForAccuracy(null, null, null, null); // no default value will be used.`

Comment: i was confused between this (what you have written) and what the heading of question stated. i will wait for an update from OP.

Comment: Indeed, the question title doesn't seem to match the rest of the question.